# After miniconda 3.3.0 (anaconda) installation, I get no module named conda.cli error

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I installed latest version of miniconda on a linux 64-bit filesystem that does not allow hard links (openAFS).
These are installation steps:

1. run installer until it fails on hard link errors
2. then modify install.py specified in $CONDA_INSTALL adding two line at the top of _link function

   if linktype==HARD_LINK: 
       linktype=SOFT_LINK
3. now execute `$PYTHON $CONDA_INSTALL --prefix=$PREFIX --pkgs-dir=$PREFIX/pkgs --link-all` and everything works

The problem is that even if python is correctly installed,

```
> miniconda/bin/python
Python 2.7.6 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jan 17 2014, 10:13:17) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I cannot run `conda`:

```
> miniconda/bin/conda
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "miniconda/bin/conda", line 3, in <module>
    from conda.cli import main
ImportError: No module named conda.cli
```

I tried to set $PATH and/or $PYTHONPATH and/or $LD_LIBRARY_PATH but without success.
Is there a way to solve this issue? Is there a way to force soft link in place of hard link during installation?
Thanks,
Angelo

Comment: Can you try this with the Miniconda 3.4.2 installers, which are avaiable at http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html.

Comment: Actually, it might not, but there is a fix for this in the next version of conda, 3.4.3.